# Html:how to add a link in the child page to (one of the) parent(s) using relative path

Tags: html

I have a local hierarchy of folders, each folder have some HTML files.
the "parent" files (the outer ones) contain links to the "child" files (in this case - a single level link - the parent links to its dirrect child) so the hierarchy is like some kind of a tree.

I want to add a link in the top of every page that will point to the parent page (the "inxed.html" file).

my code uses relative path (so there will be a possibility to move the folder and it will still work)

example:

```
  .\index.html
  .\folder1\p1.html
  .\folder1\folder2\p2.html
```

I want the possibility to have a link in the "folder1\folder2\p2.html" file that will to up the tree and will open the "index.html" page.

I preffer using HTML only (if pissible)

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In relative paths, double dots refer to the parent directory so you can use a combination of double dots if you want to go further.

`<a href="../../index.html">test</a>` should work.